# Design Principles for a Better Content Management System

Tags: content-management-system, design-principles

May be the question is so simple for you. But many times I feel it is much complicated. Everyone would have started their website with a custom cms and later moved to Wordpress, Drupal, Joomla or something similar.

I used to look for a better book or blog posts which has design decisions made for the cms to make it such a way that it can be extended. Some of the books that seems interesting to me are

1. [PHP 5 CMS Framework Development](http://www.packtpub.com/php-5-cms-framework-development-2nd-edition/book)
2. [Pro Zend Framework CMS](http://www.apress.com/9781430218791)

It will be great to see if you have came across such books or do you recommend any other books. I am not just looking for PHP, but I am interested to read any sort of books, which will help me to build the next blogger.

Things that make me interested are

1. [Blogger](http://blogger.com)
2. [drupalgardens](http://www.drupalgardens.com/)
3. [Tumblr](https://www.tumblr.com/)

and similar stuffs.

Thank you